# Moving MOSS Shared Service Provider

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharedservicesprovider

I'm in the process of moving a complete sharepoint install to a different server.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to just move the existing Shared Services Provider rather than starting from scratch?

All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to move the SSP in concert with everything else in the farm. The two things to move are 1. databases and 2. the file system.

1. A .doc file for moving all of the SharePoint databases has been published [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=141259). Microsoft will soon have an updated procedure for this published on TechNet, according to the [To The SharePoint](http://blogs.technet.com/tothesharepoint/archive/2009/01/28/3193875.aspx) blog.
2. Then to cover off any file system changes, I would set up a clean install of SharePoint (if you didn't need to already by following the document mentioned above) and do a file comparison between your source and destination SharePoint application servers. I usually use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) as its free but [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is also good. Also check any custom solutions are deployed on your destination server.

By ensuring your databases are moved correctly and all of your files are in place you should be OK. Make sure you test every custom component on your destination server before erasing the source databases and files (even better, archive the source).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a new SSP and move the applications.

How to on migration of applications [here](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/sam/archive/2009/01/11/migrating-web-applications-from-windows-sharepoint-services-to-moss-2007-by-moving-content-databases.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For moving the [SSP to a new farm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896556.aspx)
Or try the [Microsoft SharePoint Administration ToolKit v2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=263CD480-F6EB-4FA3-9F2E-2D47618505F2&displaylang=en)

[For another view of this](http://blogs.msdn.com/cjohnson/archive/2006/09/15/754902.aspx)